# python 3.5.1 won't return strings from functions

Tags: function, python-3.x, printing

I'm pretty new to python, and I'm mostly just playing around to try and teach myself.

I have a function that goes more or less like this:

```
str1 = "a"
str2 = "b"
str3 = "c"
thing = random.randint(1,2)
def fun():
  if(thing == 1):
     strVal = str1 + str2
  elif(thing == 2):
     strVal = str2 + str3
  return strVal
outp = fun
```

but when I try and `print(outp)` to the console I get an output like `<function fun at 0x000001F29138AAE8>` instead of `"ab"` or `"bc"` **how do I get the string result of** `fun` **to print instead of whatever this is?** My searches on how to get around this have only bought up documentation and examples for the print() function, which isn't really what I want.

Comment: You have to *call* the function, exactly like you do with `randint`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you don't invoke your function. A function is invoked as below

```
outp = fun()
```

That's why you see *function fun at 0x000001F29138AAE8*. Basically, Python tells you that the variable outp is a pointer to a function at the address *0x000001F29138AAE8*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Between you and @jonrsharpe I now know what I'm doing